# async.waterfall returns only the resultset of function at array[0] index of array of functions - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-async

The following code returns only the resultset of getpricingSummary

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){ 
            getpricingSummary(elementsParam, function(workloadinfo) {
            callback(workloadinfo);         
            });
    },
    function(callback){
        getPricingforResourceIdentifiers('vm/hpcloud/nova/small,image/hpcloud/nova/ami-00000075', function(pricingDetail) { 
            callback(pricingDetail);
        });
    }],
    function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async` library follows the common Node.js pattern of `error`-first callbacks.

To signify that the task was "*successful*," the 1st argument should be *falsy* (typically `null`) with any data as the 2nd or after argument.

```
callback(null, workloadinfo);
```

```
callback(null, pricingDetail);
```

```
function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        // handle the error...
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

Also note that [`async.waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) is intended for passing a result from one task to the next, arriving at just the `result` from the final task (or an `error`).

If you want to collect results from each task, try [`async.series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series). With it, `result` will be an `Array` of the data passed from each task.